# How dangerous is C++ DLL interfacing using non-exported, non-POD types?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

Let's say we build 2 C++ DLLs as part of a huge in-house codebase: a Core.DLL and Another.DLL calling the Core.DLL. Each DLL gets built with the same version of Visual Studio but with very different project settings, including e.g. C/C++->Code Generation->Struct Member Alignment.

Now let's say we pass a reference to CoreData when calling Core.DLL from Another.DLL, but the CoreData is not dllexported, it is defined by each DLL independently.

What makes it dangerous to use a non-dllexported class CoreData in such context? **Which project settings are particularly important to keep identical between the DLLs, if we had to (at gunpoint) employ the generally unsafe practice ?**

I know that we should be dll-interfacing only with POD types and abstract interfaces (COM-like), the purpose of the question is to learn what really goes on behind the curtains, if one doesn't follow those rules. I will follow these rules, just have to learn how to figure out what to fix first in a large codebase.

Below is my pseudo-code to illustrate the question.

In-depth explanations as well as links to articles or books are very welcome. I've seen a few similar questions on SO but none seemed to be deep enough.

**EDIT**: wrapped API header in #pragma pack to counter the different Struct Member Alignment project settings. Is it safe now, or are there any other project settings to keep an eye on?

Cheers!

```
// CoreDllApi.h

#pragma once

#ifdef COREDLL_EXPORTS
#define COREDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define COREDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#pragma pack(push,8)
class CoreData
{
public:
  CoreData():a(0),b(0),c(.0){}
  CoreData(int a, int b, double d):a(a),b(b),c(c){}
  virtual bool IsValid() {return true;}
  int a;
  int b;
  double c; 
};
#pragma pack(pop)

class COREDLL_API CoreRetriever
{
  static void get(int id, CoreData &out);
};

// AnotherDll.cpp:

#include "CoreDllApi.h"
#include <iostream>

static void ProcessData(int id)
{
  CoreData data;
  CoreRetriever::get(id, data); // danger?
  std::cout << data.a << ";" << data.b << ";" << data.c << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the layout is the same. Don't do this with project settings. Do it in code in the header file, using pragmas.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just wondering if it's really only about Struct Member Alignment / #pragma pack or any other project settings might be involved, assuming the allocation/deallocation has guaranteed affinity.

Comment: No idea what allocation affinity is. I don't think the constructors are a good idea either. Why don't you just use PODs with defined alignment?

Comment: Sorry for trying to invoke fancy English. By allocation affinity, I meant "allocation/deallocation is always done in the same DLL" but this would extend the scope of the question, so nevermind that - I'm just trying to learn more about project settings relevant to dll-interfacing. I can't just use PODs because the codebase is huge and there might be worse things to fix, and I can't spend as much time as I would like on general refactoring.

Comment: Perhaps you should just give up if you have to do it in ways that are known not to work.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of a greenfield project, the existing codebase is full of things that shouldn't work. But instead of giving up, I prefer to prioritise and fix the nastiest problems first. The purpose of the question was to learn how to figure out what to fix first.

Comment: I would expect different struct member alignment between different components at the time of compilation to be a problem no matter what is being done. Even if it is a static library which uses one struct alignment and another library using another will cause problems when structs are passed between components.